# Ionic2 can't build app with --prod flag

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I have developed an Ionic2 app and it runs smoothly when I build it with

```
ionic cordova build android
```

but when I try to build it with --prod flag i.e.

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

it gives following error

```
[18:09:32]  build prod started ...
[18:09:32]  clean started ...
[18:09:32]  clean finished in 63 ms
[18:09:32]  copy started ...
[18:09:32]  deeplinks started ...
[18:09:33]  deeplinks finished in 1.04 s
[18:09:33]  ngc started ...
[18:10:00]  typescript error
        src\app\app.module.ts(287,19): Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Expression form not supported.

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at D:\aafia\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
at step (D:\aafia\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (D:\aafia\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (D:\aafia\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
```

**Note**: I am using ionic-cli 3.20.0

Comment: Have you seen **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795494/angular2-aot-expression-form-not-supported) ?**

Comment: I have seen that question, but my problem is more specific to aot.

Comment: I got the same error building for iOS